# Why CSS can not understand the typing?

Tags: css

Im a new guy for this forum so please sympathy for me if i have any stupid question.
I have question like this:
+ I have the hw just the build the .css and I have the results to check. But when I try to write code the .html can not get the.css file (not change in format)

However, if i copy the .css code from the result , the .html can get it.

I make sure all the path links are right. Can any one help me
Thank you so much

Comment: Please post your code so we can better help you.

Answer (score -1):

Just like Russ J says in his comment, you need to post the code to increase your chances of getting helpful replies.

One thing to check right away is the syntax in your HTML for pulling in your **stand-alone** CSS file. It should look something like this.

**An Absolute (internal) Path**

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/some-web-dir/some-stylesheet.css">
```

Or like this.

**External Path**

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Make sure you type in everything correctly. Double check paths and filenames. Always test through your web server.

See more here https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp

Comment: I think MDN is a better resource than w3schools. Here's a similar page on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/CSS_basics